# Row maximum in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of 8,000,000 rows with 100 columns in a data.table where each column is a count. I need to find the maximum count in each row and which column this maximum is in.

I can quickly get which column has the maximum value for each row using

```
dt <- dt[, maxCol := which.max(.SD), by=pmxid]
```

but trying to get the actual maximum value using

```
dt <- dt[, nmax := max(.SD), by=pmxid]
```

is incredibly slow. I ran it for nearly 20 mins and only 200,000 row maximums had been calculated. Finding the max column took approx. 2 mins for all 8,000,000 rows.

How come finding the maximum takes so long? Shouldn't it take the same time as `which.max()` or less?

Comment: It is actually interesting question because `max` is Primitive function and should be very efficient. It would be nice if you'd provide some minimum reproducible example though. Also, is `pmxid` is just a row number? In general there is no big advantage of `data.table` when used on per row operations.

Comment: @mattdevlin `max.col` from `base R` is pretty fast.  `indx <- max.col(df, ties.method='first'); df[cbind(1:nrow(df), indx)]` gets the max value per row

Comment: @DavidArenburg: pmxid is just a numerical id but they don't match the row numbers

Comment: @mattdevlin Based on 1e6 rows with 100 columns, the max.col method gets the results in `2.18` secs

Comment: You wrote *"I can quickly get which column has the maximum value **for each row** using..."*

Comment: @akrun that's a nice approach, did you benchmark against OPs solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just did a system.time as the benchmarks willl take a lot of time (if the OP says it took more than 20 minutes).  I don't know if it is a good idea to post that as solution when the OP specifically needs a data.table solution.

Comment: @akrun, that's what I meant. If you can drop from 20 mins to 2.18 secs (using `system.time`), then you've got the solution. You can test on smaller data set too.

Comment: The `<-` assignment in `dt <- dt[,x:=y,by=z]` is not necessary if you just want a new column. You may want to check out the intro material for the package: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though, you are seeking a `data.table` solution, here is a `base R` solution which would be fast enough for your dataset.

```
indx <- max.col(df, ties.method='first')
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), indx)]
```

On a slightly bigger dataset, `system.time` comparisons revealed

```
system.time({
 indx <- max.col(df1, ties.method='first')
 res <- df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), indx)]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 2.180   0.163   2.345 



df1$pmxid <- 1:nrow(df1)
dt <- as.data.table(df1)
system.time(dt[, nmax:= max(.SD), by= pmxid])
#      user   system  elapsed 
#1265.792    2.305 1267.836
```

`base R` method to be faster than the `data.table` method in the post.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:20), 20*10, 
       replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
#if there are NAs, change it to lowest number
df[is.na(df)] <- -999

set.seed(585)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:20), 100*1e6,
 replace=TRUE), ncol=100))
df1[is.na(df1)] <- -999
```

Comment: Excellent. Takes 21.28 sec for my dataset!

Comment: @mattdevlin The title and code of the question involve data.tables, while this answer does not. Do you want to generalize your question, perhaps? You might even consider using a matrix rather than either `df` or `dt`...I suspect these operations would be faster.

Comment: For a matrix input, `colMaxs` from `matrixStats` is quite fast.

Comment: @Frank: Isn't the point of akrun's answer that a data.table is not suitable for this analysis and that it should be transformed into a data frame? I was hoping for a suitable answer that used a data.table as that is the format that my data was in (and others may have a similar problem) but using base R is a better solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. The answer doesn't mention data.tables being unsuitable, so I missed that point. I guess the onus is on @akrun to clarify within the answer. :)

Comment: @Frank Updated the post with `system.time` for the data.table method as well.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

For the maximum over columns in a data.table,

```
dt[, max:= do.call(pmax, .SD)]
```

is much faster then `dt[, nmax:= max(.SD), by= 1:nrow(dt)]`, and faster than the above `base R` solution :

```
library(data.table)
 
ncols=100
nrows=8000000
 
dfi <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(ncols*nrows), ncol = ncols, nrow = nrows))
 
df=dfi
system.time({
 indx <- max.col(df, ties.method='first')
 df$max <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df1), indx)]
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.89    1.37   10.45 

dt <- as.data.table(dfi)
system.time({
 dt[, max:= do.call(pmax, .SD)]
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.31    0.01    3.33
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you have calculated the Colmax index, use the index to retrieve the maximum in each row

```
dt[Colmax == <value>]
```

or,

```
dt[J(<values>), on = 'Colmax']
```

2. Also, wrong syntax in

```
dt[, nmax := max(.SD), by = pmxid]
```

this collates a vector of `nrow(dt) * length(.SD)` length (see the **Note** in Description of **max()**)

Instead try:

```
dt[, nmax := apply(.SD, 1, max), by = pmxid]
```

or, the parallel max:

```
dt[, nmax := pmax(.SD), by = pmxid]
```