# how can i achieve the `rowwise` function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

data like this:

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)
```

I want the max number of every row, using `dplyr` ,I can do like this:

```
df %>% rowwise()%>%mutate(maxxy = max(x,y))
```

question is how can I achieve the same result in `data.table` using `:=`

Comment: Or same `data.table` question with base R and `data.table` solution. [Row maximum in data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486654/row-maximum-in-data-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do with `pmax`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)[, maxxy := pmax(x, y)][]
```

---

With `tidyverse` also we can use `pmax`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(maxxy = pmax(x, y))
```